# Dotnet Core6 Project Windows Project Directory On Linux Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linux, asp.net-core

I am stuck in a problem. When I uploaded my dotnet core6 project publish on linux server and testing it on live. As you can see in the image

[image]

it gave my windows directory, where my dotnet project and it's controller is located and is shown in the error. I tried so many approaches like Environment.Webrootpath , hardcoded the directory path and use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory; to read the html file. but still I got this error.

code snippet:

[image]

```
string contentPath = _environment.ContentRootPath;

            string ContentType = ".pdf";

            string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss_ffffff");

            string filename = excel.SelectedService + "_" + "Answer_" + dt + ContentType;

            var pathBuild = contentPath + "Azure\\";

            if (!Directory.Exists(pathBuild))
            {

                Directory.CreateDirectory(pathBuild);

            } <= line 57
            var dir = contentPath + "\\wwwroot\\src\\Price_Template.html";
            string templateHtml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(dir);
            var template = Handlebars.Compile(templateHtml);
```

Comment: Please share the code snippet for us around the line57, we need more details.

Comment: Try to use Path and AppContext.  exmpl:`Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "YouSubDir", "youFile.ext")`

Comment: Post any code or errors as *text*, not images. Images are hard to read and can't be copied, googled or tested. What you posted doesn't show any attempt to create Excel or PDF files anyway. You can't create an Excel file by changing the extension of an HTML file. You can create *real* Excel files by using libraries like eg EPPlus, or ClosedXML. With EPPlus loading data into a sheet can be as simple as `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(myCustomers)`

Comment: first of all, sorry I forget to change the class name, that's my first task to read the excel file and put the values in it, but I didn't find any free nuget package that create and design the excel that's why I shifted to pdf.  @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: I already mentioned two. If you search NuGet or StackOverflow you'll find a *lot*. You don't have any PDF code either. PDF is a file containing print (Postscript) commands, not a document format. It has absolutely nothing to do with Excel and spreadsheets. It doesn't even have tables

Comment: I use your example and here is the result `E:\git projects\cloudbooster_backend\bin\Debug\net6.0\\Price_Template.html` it gets the file locally but when I make the release of the code I didn't find anything related to html in the release @MihalBy

Comment: it's just a curly closing bracket @JasonPan

Comment: @Patrick after release copy manualy template files to app folder. Or setup publisher to copy needent files to release location. Or use configuration paramether to specify location you templates.

Comment: In the end I create a string variable and write the html, in the c# code and it's works fine for me, I know it's not a quite good approach but this approach is works for me, to prevent error in linux server @MihalBy